# How to present partial height modal view controller from bottom to top

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have used view controller as a modal. I want to specify  its height from bottom to top. That means it opens from bottom to its height.  I have used bellow code for opening modal:

```
let popUpVc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewController") as! NewController
self.addChildViewController(popUpVc)
//Transition from bottom
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.5
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

popUpVc.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(popUpVc.view)
popUpVc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
popUpVc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Please help me..

Comment: What happens when you run that code?

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to be fine... What's the issue?

Comment: @Ashley Mills it cover the whole parent view

Comment: @Ahmad F  it working fine. Problem is that i want to show the subview specify height from bottom sothat it will not cover the whole parent view

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Modal views usually _do_ cover the whole parent view. What do you want to happen? Can you add images to illustrate your requirement?

Comment: @Ashley Mills  I have a parent view. i have child view . I want to open child over parent view. but when child view open , it covers whole parent view. for this reason, i want to give child view height . Here NewController is the child view .

Comment: Its not even appears on top of it, it *pushes* the view controller to top. Are you looking for something similar to [this](https://github.com/martinnormark/HalfModalPresentationController)?

Comment: @Ahmad F you are right ,i want to show my view bottom-half Modal. But why above this code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reading your comment it seems like you want to cover, say, the bottom half of the parent view with a modal view controller. If you're using storyboards, you can do this pretty easily using a contained view controller…

In the example below, the **Show** button is presenting the containing view controller modally, with a presentation type of **over current context**.

The view controller has a clear background, and a containing view set to half it's height. The contained (yellow) view controller has a dismiss button hooked up to an unwind segue in the green view controller.

```
@IBAction func unwind(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { }
```

All that with one line of code!

[image]

[image]

Comment: and how can I achieve this if I am not using story board pushing my view controller through code

Comment: @Ahmad Pretty sure it can't be done, at least not in iOS 15. I think you need to use views instead.